# How can I find the primary key of a table using knex.js?

Tags: knex.js

How can I find the primary key of a table using knex.js?

Using columnInfo, I can obtain the column schema:

```
knex('my_table').columnInfo().then(info => ...)
```

But this doesn't appear to identify primary keys.  Is there any way to find primary key and other constraint information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use suitable `knex.raw()` query for your database and then parse result. Knex (0.13) doesn't have any helper for it.